# python regex simple help - dealing with parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have bunch of data in this form

xxx(xx.xx) - number of digits are not fixed. like

```
312(21.1)   378(25.5)   374(25.3)   157(10.6)   260(17.6)   1481(100)
125(28.1)   91(20.4)    94(21.1)    52(11.7)    83(18.7)    445(100)
50(28.4)    44(25)  29(16.5)    12(6.8) 41(23.3)    176(100)
```

note that they are all unicode strings. lets say the number left to parentheses are A, and the number in the parentheses is B. so A(B).

what I want to do is create a function that returns list [A,B].

I know they can be done with RegExs, but I'm not really good at them. Anyway I did some search and followed tutorials, so I came up with :

```
re.search('\(.*?\)',s) # for B
re.search('.?\(',s) # for A
```

Problem is, they return parentheses with the numbers. like

```
>>s
u'312(21.1)'
>>m=re.search('\(.*?\)',s)
>>m.group()
(21.1)
```

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unescaped parenthesis to define groups:

```
>>> [g[:2] for g in re.findall(r'([0-9]+)\(([0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\)', s)]
[('312', '21.1'), ('378', '25.5'), ('374', '25.3'), ('157', '10.6'),
('260', '17.6'), ('125', '28.1'), ('91', '20.4'), ('94', '21.1'),
('52', '11.7'), ('83', '18.7'), ('50', '28.4'), ('29', '16.5'), ('12', '6.8'),
('41', '23.3'), ('176', '100')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should help better:

```
m = re.findall('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)', s)
```

What I have done is made use of the decimal point in the string. I look for a regex that has one or more digits in the range 0-9, then a decimal point and then again one or more digits in the range 0-9, and it alsoe checks for a string with digits 0-9 as an alternative. It then groups the matched expression.

Your solution gives the parentheses because you are asking the regular expression to match the parentheses in the string as well.

This returns the two numbers as a python list stored in m.

Hope it solves your problem. :)

Comment: This neither matches the number in front of the parentheses, nor does it match all of the numbers inside of the parentheses.

Comment: I tried it in a python terminal before posting here, and it works fine for me. It returns the float value inside the parenthesis, which is what the asker was having a problem with. Could you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Not all values in parentheses are floats.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh yeah. Thanks. Didn't notice that. :) Will edit the answer in a while.

Comment: Good. I still do prefer @rkhayrow's solution because it gives you the numbers in pairs.

Comment: I give this solution because the asker wants the numbers as a list [A, B] as specified in the question. No doubt @rkhayrow's solution is elegant, but then you have to do more processing and it works batch on the entire set of data.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use just strings operations, which is simpler and faster than RE in many cases.

```python
>>> s = "312(21.1)   378(25.5)   374(25.3)   157(10.6)   260(17.6)   1481(100) 125(28.1)   91(20.4)    94(21.1)    52(11.7)    83(18.7)    445(100) 50(28.4)    44(25)  29(16.5)    12(6.8) 41(23.3)    176(100)"
```

splits its into tokens

```python
>>> tokens = s.split()
>>> tokens
['312(21.1)', '378(25.5)', '374(25.3)', '157(10.6)', '260(17.6)', '1481(100)', '125(28.1)', '91(20.4)', '94(21.1)', '52(11.7)', '83(18.7)', '445(100)', '50(28.4)', '44(25)', '29(16.5)', '12(6.8)', '41(23.3)', '176(100)']
```

removes the ')' in the end

```python
>>> intermediary1 = [ entry[:-1] for entry in tokens ]
>>> intermediary1
['312(21.1', '378(25.5', '374(25.3', '157(10.6', '260(17.6', '1481(100', '125(28.1', '91(20.4', '94(21.1', '52(11.7', '83(18.7', '445(100', '50(28.4', '44(25', '29(16.5', '12(6.8', '41(23.3', '176(100']
```

breaks into 2 strings

```python
>>> intermediary2 = [ entry.split('(') for entry in intermediary1 ]
>>> intermediary2
[['312', '21.1'], ['378', '25.5'], ['374', '25.3'], ['157', '10.6'], ['260', '17.6'], ['1481', '100'], ['125', '28.1'], ['91', '20.4'], ['94', '21.1'], ['52', '11.7'], ['83', '18.7'], ['445', '100'], ['50', '28.4'], ['44', '25'], ['29', '16.5'], ['12', '6.8'], ['41', '23.3'], ['176', '100']]
```

convert to numbers (integer, float)

```python
>>> numbers = [ ( int(num1), float(num2) ) for num1, num2 in intermediary2 ]
>>> numbers
[(312, 21.1), (378, 25.5), (374, 25.3), (157, 10.6), (260, 17.6), (1481, 100.0), (125, 28.1), (91, 20.4), (94, 21.1), (52, 11.7), (83, 18.7), (445, 100.0), (50, 28.4), (44, 25.0), (29, 16.5), (12, 6.8), (41, 23.3), (176, 100.0)]
```

or in a shorter way using list comprehension:

```python
>>> tokens = [ entry[:-1].split('(') for entry in s.split()]
>>> numbers = [ ( int(num1), float(num2) ) for num1, num2 in tokens ]
>>> numbers
[(312, 21.1), (378, 25.5), (374, 25.3), (157, 10.6), (260, 17.6), (1481, 100.0), (125, 28.1), (91, 20.4), (94, 21.1), (52, 11.7), (83, 18.7), (445, 100.0), (50, 28.4), (44, 25.0), (29, 16.5), (12, 6.8), (41, 23.3), (176, 100.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import sys

li = []
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if not line: break
  for i in line.split():
    m = re.search('(.*)\((.*)\)', i)
    tup = (m.group(1), m.group(2))
    li.append(tup)

print li
```

sample output:

```
$ python y
312(21.1)   378(25.5)   374(25.3)   157(10.6)   260(17.6)   1481(100)
[('312', '21.1'), ('378', '25.5'), ('374', '25.3'), ('157', '10.6'), ('260', '17.6'), ('1481', '100')]
```

Comment: In fact I just tested it before posting -- here's the output pasted from my shell window:

Marc-Cohens-iMac% python y
312(21.1)
312 21.1

Works fine for me on Python 2.7.3. Why would you say I didn't test it?

Comment: And your input file contained more than one pair of numbers on one line (as in the question)?

Comment: No, I'm illustrating the concept (using parens to group sub-parts of REs for referencing after search), not giving a complete solution. You'll also note that I added an input reading loop which is not part of the questioner's request. I'm showing how to solve the problem, not giving a verbatim soution.

Comment: Yes, but using `.*` is definitely the wrong approach. It only works on a constrained problem (defined by you) and can't be applied to the actual problem.

Comment: You're right - I fixed my solution to address the problem. Thanks for catching that!